# xslt - show all data values in tag

Tags: xml, xslt

Given this shrinked xml I would like to get xslt desired output as I wrote in the bottom of this question.

It should take data from both DataStores (first is for header values and the second one is for it's items).

I see there's an error in my xslt script in x-path selector and foreach loop part.

**Given this XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RUNRESULT STATE="SUCCESS" START="2020-09-07 08:48:11" STOP="2020-09-07 08:48:13" DATABASENUMBER="10" TRANSFORMATION="0000036">
  <DETAIL>
    <RECORD SUBJECTID="70521192" CLASSID="343" GUNID="00000A00009J15ZII0" FOLDERID="14858" REFERENCE="pro repliku" NAME="PRO VYVOLÁNÍ REPLIKACE DO MODULY" CLASSNAME="Kmenová karta zboží / materiálu" FOLDERNAME="Modula - pomocný" TIMESTAMP="0000000061FBCCDF" datum_vzniku="2020-08-17 10:55:25" last_update="2020-09-07 08:47:29" />
  </DETAIL>
  <storedProcedureResult>
    <items>
      <item>
        <RECORD SUBJECTID="70521192" CLASSID="343" GUNID="00000A00009J15ZII0" FOLDERID="14858" REFERENCE="pro repliku" NAME="PRO VYVOLÁNÍ REPLIKACE DO MODULY" CLASSNAME="Kmenová karta zboží / materiálu" FOLDERNAME="Modula - pomocný" TIMESTAMP="0000000061FBCCDF" datum_vzniku="2020-08-17 10:55:25" last_update="2020-09-07 08:47:29" />
        <Datastores>
          <Datastore TableName="invoiceHeader">
            <Definition>
              <Columns>
                <Column Name="c_cs" DataType="int" />
                <Column Name="c_objed" DataType="string" />
              </Columns>
            </Definition>
            <DataRows>
              <DataRow c_cs="68306186" c_objed="ODH2001295" />
              <DataRow c_cs="68402059" c_objed="ODH2002270" />
              <DataRow c_cs="71447530" c_objed="ODH2029909" />
              <DataRow c_cs="71461025" c_objed="ODH2030171" />
              <DataRow c_cs="71463689" c_objed="ODH2030207" />
              <DataRow c_cs="71463926" c_objed="ODH2030209" />
              <DataRow c_cs="71465079" c_objed="ODH2030222" />
              <DataRow c_cs="71465256" c_objed="ODH2030226" />
              <DataRow c_cs="71465656" c_objed="ODH2030233" />
              <DataRow c_cs="71465662" c_objed="ODH2030234" />
            </DataRows>
          </Datastore>
          <Datastore TableName="invoiceItems">
            <Definition>
              <Columns>
                <Column Name="c_cs" DataType="int" />
                <Column Name="c_objed" DataType="string" />
                <Column Name="odber_dodav" DataType="string" />
                <Column Name="ORD_TIPOOP" DataType="string" />
                <Column Name="zdroj_ref" DataType="string" />
                <Column Name="poc" DataType="decimal" />
                <Column Name="c_r" DataType="int" />
              </Columns>
            </Definition>
            <DataRows>
              <DataRow c_cs="68306186" c_objed="ODH2001295" odber_dodav="Divize ND + SERVIS" ORD_TIPOOP="P" zdroj_ref="H223849" poc="1.000000" c_r="13" />
              <DataRow c_cs="68306186" c_objed="ODH2001295" odber_dodav="Divize ND + SERVIS" ORD_TIPOOP="P" zdroj_ref="L209135" poc="1.000000" c_r="15" />
              <DataRow c_cs="68306186" c_objed="ODH2001295" odber_dodav="Divize ND + SERVIS" ORD_TIPOOP="P" zdroj_ref="AL80154" poc="4.000000" c_r="17" />
              <DataRow c_cs="68306186" c_objed="ODH2001295" odber_dodav="Divize ND + SERVIS" ORD_TIPOOP="P" zdroj_ref="R116911" poc="2.000000" c_r="18" />
              <DataRow c_cs="68306186" c_objed="ODH2001295" odber_dodav="Divize ND + SERVIS" ORD_TIPOOP="P" zdroj_ref="R533599" poc="1.000000" c_r="19" />
              <DataRow c_cs="68306186" c_objed="ODH2001295" odber_dodav="Divize ND + SERVIS" ORD_TIPOOP="P" zdroj_ref="L80015" poc="2.000000" c_r="21" />
              <DataRow c_cs="68306186" c_objed="ODH2001295" odber_dodav="Divize ND + SERVIS" ORD_TIPOOP="P" zdroj_ref="H207542" poc="30.000000" c_r="22" />
              <DataRow c_cs="68306186" c_objed="ODH2001295" odber_dodav="Divize ND + SERVIS" ORD_TIPOOP="P" zdroj_ref="SW80HCOUS" poc="1.000000" c_r="23" />
              <DataRow c_cs="68306186" c_objed="ODH2001295" odber_dodav="Divize ND + SERVIS" ORD_TIPOOP="P" zdroj_ref="R204521" poc="1.000000" c_r="24" />
              <DataRow c_cs="68306186" c_objed="ODH2001295" odber_dodav="Divize ND + SERVIS" ORD_TIPOOP="P" zdroj_ref="AH171602" poc="1.000000" c_r="25" />
          </Datastore>
        </Datastores>
      </item>
    </items>
  </storedProcedureResult>
</RUNRESULT>
```

**Given this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">


<xsl:for-each select="/RUNRESULT/storedProcedureResult/items/item/Datastores/Datastore[2]/DataRows">

<xxx>
    <objednavka>
        <hlavicka>
            <c_objed><xsl:value-of select="c_objed"/></c_objed>
        </hlavicka>
        <polozka>
            <zdroj_ref><xsl:value-of select="zdroj_ref"/></zdroj_ref>
        </polozka>
    </objednavka>
</xxx>

</xsl:for-each>


</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Having this output:**

```
<xxx>
   <objednavka>
      <hlavicka>
         <c_objed/>
      </hlavicka>
      <polozka>
         <zdroj_ref/>
      </polozka>
   </objednavka>
</xxx>
```

**Desired output:**

```
<xxx>
    <objednavka>
        <hlavicka>
            <c_objed>ODH2001295</c_objed>
        </hlavicka>

        <polozka>
            <zdroj_refer>H223849</zdroj_refer>
            <zdroj_refer>L209135</zdroj_refer>
            <zdroj_refer>AL80154</zdroj_refer>
            <zdroj_refer>R116911</zdroj_refer>
            <zdroj_refer>R533599</zdroj_refer>
            <zdroj_refer>L80015</zdroj_refer>
            <zdroj_refer>SW80HCOUS</zdroj_refer>
            <zdroj_refer>R204521</zdroj_refer>
            <zdroj_refer>AH171602</zdroj_refer>
            <zdroj_refer>R55326</zdroj_refer>
        </polozka>
    </objednavka>
</xxx>
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm sorry I'm not clear enough :/ Basically I want desired output as I wrote it in the bottom of the question - it's called Desired output and it contains my desired xml table structure.

Comment: Basically you're asking for someone to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: I don't need anyone to write it from scratch. I just need a little help because I cannot figure out how to output any data... In tutorials there are always pretty and simple xml examples but I'm stucked since there's tag with multiple values. I mean <DataRow c_objed="123456789" zdroj_refer="ODH123456789">. I don't know how to parse that data.

Comment: Your desired output is so extraordinarily different than your current output that it's clear that you're not asking for help with a specific misunderstanding or problem.  Whether you admit it or not, your question amounts to a request for someone to write code for you or handhold you through multiple steps of a tutorial.  That's not the purpose of this site.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, kjhughes - understood and sorry. I get your point. Few secs later I edited my xslt script and now it matches my desired output structure. So my question is why for-each doesn't match anything even though I know my x-path is correct :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is why for-each doesn't match anything

Actually your xsl:for-each does match something: it matches the `DataRows` element of the 2nd `Datastore`. Otherwise your output would be completely empty.

However, if you want to get a value from each `DataRow`, you must go one step deeper. And you need to select attributes as such, using `@`. Perhaps something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/RUNRESULT/storedProcedureResult/items/item/Datastores/Datastore[2]/DataRows">
    <xxx>
        <objednavka>
            <hlavicka>
                <c_objed>
                    <xsl:value-of select="DataRow[1]/@c_objed"/>
                </c_objed>
            </hlavicka>
            <polozka>
                <xsl:for-each select="DataRow">
                    <zdroj_ref>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@zdroj_ref"/>
                    </zdroj_ref>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </polozka>
        </objednavka>
    </xxx>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Wau thanks! 2 mins ago I've noticed all tutorials showing how to extract data from tags like this - <DataRow>Some data</DataRow> but my xml is different. It has this structure <DataRow c_cs="Some data" /> and since I didn't know about referencing values with @ I wasn't able to get that data. Thank you michael! :) And I hope last question - is there a chance to write xslt script that gets always header (DataRow/@c_objed) with its items (@zdroj_ref)?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your last question. I should add that I don't fully understand your XML either (perhaps you left too much out). All the invoice items have the same `c_objed` - but the invoice header has other values too. I suggest you open a new question and clarify your new requirements.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to explain better. Right now I'm able to display values, it's perfect but I need different structure. I will post answer with modified xslt and I think you will understand what's on my mind :)

Comment: I suggest you post a question, not an answer. SO is not a forum.

Comment: you mean new question? Or maybe I can edit original question. What should I do?

Comment: I mean new question.

Comment: I just edited the original one :( Sorry. And now if I make new one then it will be deleted I guess ?

Comment: I have rolled your question back to what it was when I answered it. Post a new question.

Comment: Done, thank you. New question is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63794407/xslt-format-new-xml-structure